# Random numbers for Master Key and Key_block

Tags: keys, key-exchange, tls, hkdf

Exploration through RFCs concludes that random numbers used in the creation of Master Key and Key Block(Key material for Encryption Key and Mac Secret) are from ServerHello.random and ClientHello.random. Only these random numbers are used in both the cases. No separate Client and Server randoms for Key Block and Master Key.

Is this correct ?

If Yes, In the TLS KDF why there are separate set of random numbers for generating Key Block and Master Key ?

TLS KDF pdf : http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/components/askdfvs.pdf